# Is $2^{O(n)}$ the same as $O(2^n)$ for big O time complexity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Is $2^{O(n)}$ the same as $O(2^n)$?

Taking $\log_2$ of $2^{O(n)}$ I get that $\log_2 2^{O(n)}= O(n)\log_2 2= O(n)$ such that $2^{O(n)}$ is bound by a linear time complexity ($O(n)$). From this conclusion I first thought that $2^{O(n)} \neq O(2^n) $ (since the latter is exponential). However since "big O" time complexity essentially gives an upper bound could one still argue that these are equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No: $4^n = 2^{2n}$ is $2^{O(n)}$ but not $O(2^n)$, for example.